# Implement Audio Visualizer in Android 2.1

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, visualizer

I have developed an Audio player in Android with minSdkVersion=7 i.e Android 2.1. Now I want implement Audio Visualizer as given in [AudioFxDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html) example.

The problem is I can not use [AudioFxDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html) example code as it uses [Equalizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) and [Visualizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) the classes which are available in Android 2.3(API 9) and above.

**My question** is, can I implement Audio visualizer for Android 2.1. If you point me to some example code, it would be the best.